# How to test if "Downloading..." text is displayed when the loading state is true using Enzyme and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component called ChoiceOfFundForm that includes a download button. When the download button is clicked, it triggers the handleClick function, which sets the loading state to true and calls the downloadChoiceOfFund action. After the download is complete (or in case of an error), the loading state is set back to false.

I want to write a test case to ensure that when the loading state is true, the component correctly displays the "Downloading..." text using the DownloadingContainer component. I am using Enzyme and jest for testing. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
const DownloadingContainer = styled('div')({
    color: 'rgb(92, 111, 123)',
});

const ChoiceOfFundForm = ({
    // props and state definitions
}) => {
    // ...

    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <ContributionFormLink
                    // props
                    onClick={handleClick}
                />
                {loading && (
                    <DownloadingContainer data-testid="downloadingContainer">
                        ...Downloading
                    </DownloadingContainer>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

and my failed test:

```
jest.mock('react', () => ({
...jest.requireActual('react'),
useState: (initialState) => [initialState, mockSetLoading],
}));

it('should show "Downloading..." text when loading state is true', () => {
    mockSetLoading(true);
    const wrapper = shallow(<ChoiceOfFundForm store={store} />).dive();
    const downloadingContainer = wrapper.find('[data-testid="downloadingContainer"]');

    expect(downloadingContainer).text().toEqual('...Downloading');
});
```

and my error currently:

TypeError: expect(...).text is not a function

I just seem to be going around in circles

Comment: In your test you should have some logic to target the button and click it, then wait for the DOM to update so the `DownloadingContainer` component is mounted and targetable. This all might be easier with `react-testing-library` as Enzyme is effectively deprecated for a couple years now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have there is that you called `text()` from Jest `expect` that for sure doesn't have this method.
You should call `text()` from `downloadingContainer` object.

Like

`expect(downloadingContainer.text()).toEqual('...Downloading');`

So trivial issues is very hard to find, I know. :)